# Subtract subselect values in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, subquery

I'm working with Hibernate and I want to obtain a substraction from two values fetched from two diffeent subqueries but I am gettin the following error:

> SQLGramarEception: could not execute query

```
SELECT termQuery.term.id,
   (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(termResult2.position),101) FROM termQuery2.results termResult2 WHERE termResult2.url.hostname MEMBER subscription.account.domains) as **prevPosition**, 
   (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(termResult.position),101) FROM termQuery.results termResult WHERE termResult.url.hostname MEMBER subscription.account.domains) as **currentPosition**,
   prevPosition - currentPosition as change --<<<<<<
FROM TermSubscription subscription, TermQuery termQuery, TermQuery termQuery2
WHERE subscription.account.id=1197 
    AND termQuery.term=subscription.term 
    AND termQuery.provider.id=2
    AND termQuery.queryDate.yearWeek = '201242'
    AND termQuery2.term=termQuery.term
    AND termQuery2.provider.id=termQuery.provider.id
    AND termQuery2.queryDate.yearWeek = '201241'
ORDER BY subscription.term.id, termQuery.queryDate.yearWeek
```

I know that it is not possible to substract those two values like that but I don't know the way to do it. So, what would be the way?
Thanks

Comment: I would redo it, joining against the subselects (ie, each subselect to get the position for all people, with the join ON clause on the persons id) so you get values for them directly, and then calculate the value you want in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @Kickstart: There is no ON clause in HQL, and subqueries can only be used in select and where clauses in HQL.

Answer (score 0):

select only the 3 other values, and while iterating on the results of the query, subtract the `currentPosition` from the `prevPosition`, in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your help but Im not sure that solution suits my problem because my goal is to order the result by the most changed position -once I have it- and after to store the fetched values in its corresponding pojo. This is why I wouldnt like to mess aroung with the obtained data in java.

Comment: You could also sort in Java.